# How to allow for dot and comma to be entered in this input field?

Tags: javascript, html

The line below restrict the input to be numbers only. How can this be adjusted to accept dot and comma?

```html
Numbers only: <input oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/(?![0-9])./gmi,'')"></input>
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may replace on the pattern `[^0-9.,]+`:

```html
<input oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.,]+/gmi,'')"></input>
```

Note that technically we should also disallow more than one decimal point, and we also should not allow thousands comma separators in the wrong place.